# Run extension-app code when order is created in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template, shopify-api-node

I am building an extension-app for Shopify. So it means its hosted by shopify and integrated into admin panel. Meaning that I do not have embedded app or external API server.

I hoped that somehow I could trigger the extension-app code on some shopify signal when new order is created. But I don't see any other way to do it other than using shopify web hooks and custom API backend server. My only concern with webhooks as per https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/webhooks#limitations is that the delivery isn't always guaranteed. I cannot allow for scenario where webhook work.

I saw shopify has this thing called 'Shopify Functions' as well as Theme Ajax API but I dont think this would handle my case either. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: You can implement reconciliation jobs to periodically fetch data from Shopify to handle missing webhooks.

Comment: Hey @bilal-akbar, thanks for your comment. Yes that would be good fallback mechanism. In your experience, did this happen very often that webhooks didn't get called at all?

Comment: I haven't noticed this personally. But then again I do not have any high load shopify app or something. But for my personal projects and during tests I did not notice missing web hooks.

Comment: As far as I've learned from shopify docs - Your extension-only app will be ran automatically when an order is created that is if the extension is order related. 

For example: When a discount related extension is created which runs in the cart, the function will automatically run each time a product is added to the cart.

Comment: thanks @WakilAhmed for an insightful comment. Would you mind sharing the shopify docs link that you are talking about?